# Linking Containers with Pipeline

Tags: docker, containers, ibm-cloud

Using the ICE command line, I am able to create two Docker containers that are linked.  The first container is my backend node server which listens on port 3000.  The second container is an http server that listens on 80.  The http server proxies the api requests to linked server's port 3000.  It works as expected.  I need to replicate this setup using the deployment pipeline.

How do I link containers using the deployment pipeline?  Am I supposed to create the two linked as a container group? It seems like I should be able to setup a container group that would scale the linked containers but I haven't been able to find documentation on how to do this.

Comment: Here are the command line i'm using to link the continers:   

`ice run -p 3000 --name reserved-server registry.ng.bluemix.net/reservedserverimg/reserved-server`  

`ice run -p 80 --link reserved-server:reserved --name reserved-httpd registry.ng.bluemix.net/reservedserverimg/reserved-http`

Comment: It seems that I could just build the containers using the same method that I use on the command line in the build script part of the build job. Then I would just have two separate build steps, one for each of the two containers.  In the deploy step, i link the two images together.  I resorted to this method to make it work, but it seems like there should be a better way.

Answer (score 3):

Please take a look at the [IBM Containers Docs - Creating a container group by using the Delivery Pipeline](https://www.ng.bluemix.net/docs/containers/container_group_pipeline_ov.html). There you should find the information you need about the delivery pipeline and the container groups.

Comment: An answer like this really isn't that helpful as it's equivalent to saying "RTFM". Can you expand a little bit on what the question asker should do to link his containers with the pipeline?